# Redhat 7 instance not registered

Tags: redhat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have installed a Redhat 7 instance on GCE that will host a SAS installation.
Currently, we are stuck with the SAS installation process because the Redhat server is not registered.

The command "subscription-manager version" returns the following:

```
server type: This system is currently not registered.
subscription management server: 0.9.51.24-1
subscription management rules: 5.15.1
subscription-manager: 1.19.21-1.el7
python-rhsm: 1.19.9-1.el7
```

How come our Redhat instance is not registered while we are invoiced for the Redhat licence by Google? How can we register the system?

Comment: Are you using the public Red Hat image provided by Google? I just spin a VM and it does not have the "subscription-manager" installed by default. That makes me believe that the licensing scheme might be manages in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one else that might be interested in RHEL licensing scheme on GCE, here is what I got from the support:

- The Red Hat systems on GCE do not come registered nor with a subscription.
- On GCP, we only provide the core functionality while Red Hat subscription needs to be done on your side.
- For subscribers of RH Enterprise products, Red Hat Cloud Access enables enterprise customers to migrate their current subscriptions for use on Google Compute Engine.

Comment: I'm honestly curious. What is the purpose of paying the premium OS fee to Google for RHE instances if you don't get the benefits that come with RHE?

Comment: This is a question I have no answer to. I'm used to Ubuntu servers we had to use Redhat for a specific software but I'm not inclined to it again. It looks like going through Redhat directly to then deploy on GCE is a better idea.